# Applying the negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows:
The probability that a randomly selected car is white is $0.2$. What is the distribution of  $V$ where $V$ is the number of white cars that pass an observer before the third non-white one.

I think it has a probability mass function:
$$p(x) = \binom{x-1}{2}(0.8)^3(0.2)^{x-3},$$
where $x$ takes values in the range of $3$ onwards.

The answer in my book says that its probability mass function is
$$p(x) = \binom{x-1}{2}(0.2)^3(0.8)^{x-3},$$
where $x$ takes values in the range of $0$ onwards.

Notice that the range does not make sense!!

Am I correct? or are we both wrong?

Comment: Note that $V$ is the number of WHITE cars before three non-white car. So, the range must start at 0.

Comment: Ok. I don't think I understand the question properly then. please could you help me understand?

Comment: What is the correct distribution? Is the book correct?

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is Almost correct. That is, your p.m.f. describe the total (lets call $X$) of cars viewed by the observer, including the 3 non-white.

Note that the number of white cars is given by $V = X - 3$. So you just need to fix some constants in your expression.

To observe $v$ white cars, we must observe $x=v+3$ cars, being 3 non-whites. Moreover, the last one must be a non-white. Fixing the last car, we have v+2 cars, where 2 is non-white that can switch positions with each other. In that way:

$$ p(v) = \binom{v+2}{2}(0.8)^3(0.2)^v$$

This is the pmf of an negative binomial distribution, when the quantity of interest is the number of fails.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Thank you Renato! :)